# Prestashop Error: 'install' directory is missing after moving site to other server

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

Prestashop Error: 'install' directory is missing after moving site to other server

Site Name : http://zettsports.com.au/

Comment: where do you get this error? Your site shows no errors so i am asking if it is back office or front.

Comment: Error is Fixed Thanks for comment :)

Answer (score 4):

If anyone encounters this Please check your config folder, make sure you have all files and setting.inc is set correctly
Thanks